# Is there a way to show mat-calendar with multi-month view using angular material?

Tags: angular, calendar, angular-material, angular-calendar

I want to show the dates from at least two months at a time in `mat-calendar`. I have realised that there are only 3 expected values for `currentView` as `month`, `year` and `multi-year`. None of them solve my requirement. I tried to use `multi-month` but this value was not accepted by `mat-calendar`. Please let me know if there is way to serve my requirement.

Comment: Hello, mahesh peddi. did you manage to do this? How did you do it? Thanks.